# How to display character array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the below code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char string[] = {1, 2, 3};
  char* my_pointer = string;
  printf("%c", *my_pointer);
}
```

Am expecting the ASCII character `'1'` to be displayed on screen.

ASCII character `'1'` is `49` with binary representation as `00110001`

Comment: 1 does not equal 49

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider typo. Am expecting `1` to be type casted to `'1'`, because `string` is `char` array

Comment: There is no typo. You're inputting a char with the value of 1 and expecting 49 ('1') to print.

Comment: @overexchange converting `1` to `char` gives character code `1` (not character code `49`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give it characters when initializing:

```
char string[] = {'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

or you can initialize using a string

```
char string[] = "123";
```

When you use numbers like

```
  char string[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

it will print the ASCII character corresponding to the number 1 (which is most likely not generating any output).

If you want to initialize using numbers, you must do:

```
  char string[] = {49, 50, 51};
```

Comment: Why do I need to give `'1'` instead of `1`. C is a loosely typed language. `1` has to be type casted to `'1'`, because it is `string` is `char` array

Comment: The syntax `'1'` correspond to the character `1` which is equal to the number 49. You use the syntax for characters, e.g. `'a'` for the letter a

Comment: Oh you mean `SOH` character has value `1` in ASCII chart, so could not print

Comment: [C is not a loosely \[weakly\] typed language](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/looslang.htm)!

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
char string[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Declares an array of three `char` values initialised with three integer literals. To initialise with a char literal use the single quote operators `'` as below.

```
char string[] = {'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

Note that when initialising the array you need to include the null terminator as I have done above, otherwise your call to `printf` will result in *undefined behaviour*. In your comment to one of the above answers you ask

> Why do I need to give '1' instead of 1. C is a loosely typed language.
>   1 has to be type casted to '1', because it is string is char array

Remember that a `char` under the hood is just a representation of a number; the 'character literal' syntax is just syntactic sugar that allows you to create character constants in a more semantic way.

```
char variable1 = 49;
char variable2 = '1';
```

In this instance, the two statements are exactly equivalent. If C should cast in the way you suggested, should it cast `49` to 4, 9, or perhaps a string "49"? This is unclear. C is a lazy language - it doesn't do any clever trickery to help you, so when you set a char to the value 49, it will assign the numerical value.